# How to set default runlevel?

Tags: 14.04, runlevel

I would like to know how to set a default runlevel? This is to ensure that my computer directly boots at the set level .

Comment: The concept of runlevels is somewhat depreciated with both upstart and systemd.  With systemd it is termed "states" - nice reiew - https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/794615-systemd-runlevels-and-service-management . runlevels are still emulated in some distros, most still use the concept of runlevels 0 , 1, 6 . On Debian and Ubunt 2 = 3 = 4 = 5. For upstart see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpstartHowto#How_do_I_change_the_runlevel.3F

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [simpler way](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#changing-the-default-runlevel) is to edit `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` and change:

```
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
```

To:

```
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=N
```

Where N is the desired runlevel.

---

The runlevel can be set using kernel parameters. Edit `/etc/default/grub`, and change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="N"
```

Where N is the runlevel you want. Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You can also force a one-time boot to a different runlevel by editing the command line from the GRUB menu at boot.

---

In practice, remember that runlevels 2-5 have no difference in the default Ubuntu setup. So don't expect anything different to happen if you boot to runlevel 3.