# NetworkManager does not start automatically

Tags: networking, network-manager, runlevel

I used this [QUESTION](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615634/how-to-set-default-runlevel) to configure the default of Ubuntu 14.10 to start in RUNLEVEL 1

but  when I switch to another RUNLEVEL (2,3,or 5) , there is no network connection and I have to start the network using command `NetworkManger`

is this a normal behaviour , and if not how to configure the network to start automatically when I switch run levels

Answer (score 0):

Network manager is in fact a (local) server, that acts on requests of a (local) client. This client is normaly the network applet in a desktop and thus of course belongs to a GUI session.

Small explain

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| run level |             name                |     Description                                                             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     2     |         Multi-User Mode         | Does not configure network interfaces and does not export networks services |
|     3     | Multi-User Mode with Networking | Starts the system normally                                                  |
|     4     | Not used / user definable       | For special purposes                                                        | 
|     5     | System normally with GUI        | Run level 3 + display manager                                               |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Propose for you is to disable Network Manager and configure interfaces manually.

Stop the Network Manager process

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

Disable it

```
echo "manual" | sudo tee /etc/init/network-manager.override
```

or you can remove NetworkManager from the system

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
```

Then you need to manually set network

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and write `ip`,`netmask` ...

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.x.xx
gateway xxx.xxx.x.x
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.x
network xxx.xxx.x.x
broadcast xxx.xxx.x.xxx
```

After entering all the details you need to restart networking services using the following command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Setting up DNS

Edit `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

write

```
nameserver dns_server_ip
nameserver dns2_server_ip
```

After this step, your network will be configured without NM and will be work on run level 3 and 5.

Edit 1

You can start any app when login into `GUI` automatically if you put a .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart to run applications after a user login. This may have following content:

`nano ~/.config/autostart/nm.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=<Name of application as displayed>
Exec=<command to execute>
Icon=<full path to icon>
Comment=<optinal comments>
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Comment: as far as i know , runlevel 2 to 5 are almost the same and they all have GUI , and this is what I get when I use `init 2` , and my question is  how i start NetworkManger automatically not remove it

Comment: I made Edit 1 in answer

Comment: `This client is normaly the network applet in a desktop and thus of course belongs to a GUI session` Wait, what about booting to command line ? If NetworkManager starts with GUI login, why then it works when booting to tty ? `nmcli` ? There's also dmesg entries for NetworkManager when system boots